# How can I connect my BI tools to YouTube API (ODBC)?

Tags: datatables, youtube, odbc, tableau-api, youtube-data-api

As far as I can tell, it's free to query against the YouTube API.  I have access to Tableau, so now I just need to understand how to connect Tableau to YouTube tables.  I can't find any info on this.  Please help!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for Tableau's [Web Data Connector](https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/) extensibility option.

This will require writing some code (or discovering via existing code samples) in JavaScript to create a link to the YouTube API.

(APIs don't use ODBC protocol as far as I know.)